# Angular2: Routing to the same page and changing query parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I have an `Angular 2` project where I want to do the following:

Lets say I have a `Component` which has a datatable that supports paging and sorting.
What I want to achieve is that every time the table page/size and sorting changes, to also change the `URL Parameters`.

However when I access the particular component from the `Router` I also want to set the default URL parameters on the `Address Bar`
So the sequence I thought of was the following:

1. Navigate to my component with no parameters
2. Set up the query parameters `Observable` on `NgOnInit` and upon receiving the first parameters
   reload the url again to set the default ones
3. Every time a parameter changes navigate to current route. This will change the params so the query parameter `Observable` will emit the event. Then a new `Ajax` call will be triggered.

Now this probably isnt the best idea but the problems I have are the following:
1. The first time two `Ajax` calls are triggered
2. If I click on the "current route" link on the page `NgOnInit` doesn't trigger so I cannot replace in the address bar the default parameters.

A short version of the code is the following (I have purposely omitted imports/@Component annotation etc):

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private params = {page: 0, size: 5}
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;
  private router: Router;
  private data = []

  private pageLoaded = false;
  private queryParamsSubscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(
    private router: Router, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
    private http: Http) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.queryParamsSubscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams
        .debounceTime(100)
        .switchMap((routeParams) => {
          //assign the Url Parameters to my params object
          this.params = Object.keys(routeParams)
            .reduce((params, key) => {
              params[key] = routeParams[key];
              return params
            }, this.params);
          if(!this.pageLoaded) {
            //if the page is not leaded yet run reloadRoute and only replace 
            //the url (true flag) without adding to browser history
            //this will only run once
            this.reloadRoute(true);
            this.pageLoaded = true;
          }
          //finally perform the ajax call with the new params
          //so basically whenever the url parameters change
          //then fire an ajax call
          return this.findAll(this.params)
        })
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
          }
        );
  }

  //request data from the server
  findAll(params: any) {
    let urlParams: : URLSearchParams = //create urlParams from param
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, new RequestOptions({search: urlParams}))
     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
     .catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
       return Observable.from(err);
     })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.queryParamsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  onChangePageSize(size) {
    this.params['size'] = page.size
  }

  onChangePage(page) {
    this.params['page'] = page.page - 1;
    this.reloadRoute();
  }

  //this basically is called every time a parameter changes
  //so I navigate to the same page with the new parameters
  private reloadRoute(replaceUrl: boolean = false) {

    this.router.navigate(
      [this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.path], 
      {queryParams: params, replaceUrl: replaceUrl}
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar, but don't subscribe to the queryParams. Instead I evaluate them from the route-snapshot in the constructor and feed my internal observables with the data, so the view can display whatever the queryParams say.

When the user moves to the "next page", I just feed my observables with the new offset (result view updates automatically) and navigate to the same page with the new queryParams, if they are different from the last queryParams (=> no page reload, no trigger on queryParams, no extra http request).